# Returns made by async Dispatcher Invoke not considered as return by method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

For code reuse, I am trying to return an async value after its passed through dispatcher invoke yet the method isn't considering it as a return. Why?

```
    internal static async Task<bool> iASK(string message, string title)
    {
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
                    {
                        return await ASK(message, title);
                    });
        //throw new Exception("iASK's question didn't receive response.");
    }
```

Throwing an exception at the end of the method stopped the method's complaint but now I only receive the thrown exception.

---

Update 1
The async method is calling the opensource MahApps MessageBox

```
    internal static async Task<bool> ASK(string message, string title)
    {
        return MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.MessageDialogResult.Affirmative == 
            await CustomShowMessage(message, title, MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, 
            new MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.MetroDialogSettings() { AffirmativeButtonText = "Yes", NegativeButtonText = "No" });
    }
```

The MessageBox runs within the UI thread but I need a response from my separate thread before continuing my program.

I currently call it by running

```
                await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
                {
                    await ASK(message, title);
                });
```

with in my primary methods. I implemented the iASK method for simpler code reuse.

I don't know how to call an async method via BeginInvoke.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Invoke` at all.  One of the major features of `await` is that continuations all run in the context of the caller, which should be the UI context if the method needs to manipulate the UI.  You should just be calling the method from the UI thread, awaiting some non-UI work, and then just updating the UI in the continuation.

Comment: @Servy I built an app on top of MVVMLight and MahApps. I'm not sure how I would call anything from the UI context without breaking MVVM. Do you know any "proper" sample codes where they implement a program that may need to question the user (via an async MessageBox) while keeping the UI fluid?

Comment: All event handlers are going to be in the UI thread; you just need to not *leave* the UI context.

Comment: (I've deleted my answer as your answer was basically what I was going to end up posting. I still don't think it's a terribly clean approach, but it works...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Servy I would love to build a cleaner approach so if you find any complex code on the web that properly implements asynchronous programming, please send me a link. I currently can't recognize what is considered clean/unclean. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I solved it by

```
    internal static async Task<bool> iASK(string message, string title)
    {
           return await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
           {
                return await ASK(message, title);
           });
    //throw new Exception("iASK's question didn't receive response.");
    }
```